# jQuery Mobile layout in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Short:

Do you put the data-role portions (header|content|footer) in your layout/master page or in each view in ASP.NET MVC?

Long:

Trying to find the 'best practice' with handling jQuery mobile layout. The docs (and some others) show:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
        ...
</head> 
<body>
<div  data-role="page"> 
    <div  data-role="header">...</div> 
    <div  data-role="content">@RenderBody()</div> 
    <div  data-role="footer">...</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However I have seen this too :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
        ...
</head> 
<body>
<div  data-role="page">     
     @RenderBody()
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

With each view having:

```
<div  data-role="page"> 
    <div  data-role="header">...</div> 
    <div  data-role="content">...</div> 
    <div  data-role="footer">...</div> 
</div>
```

So, do you define the header|content|footer in each 'view' in ASP.NET or in the layout/master? Is one better? Does it matter at all?

Comment: In your second example you would end up with a page nested inside another page. Is this what you intended?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Personally, I've been using the second practice for Don't-Repeat-Yourself sake.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. How do you handle button navigation that context sensitive in headers and footers if it is in the layout page?

Comment: Oops my bad. I meant the second one. Changed original post accordingly. <div data-role="header"> is normally in each view. If navigation part is common for the controller, I create a separate partial view and use Html.Partial to display in each view.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that navigation (using the back button) only works correctly when you use the first option (DRY). I am facing the same issue. If I want different header content how do you change this if you have one layout page. I think the way to go is to create sections in the master layout page and enable them per view as required.

```
 RenderSection("SectionName")
```